# How to generate the apk of an application in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm new in Meteor js framework and I'm trying to create my first apk of my app by following the steps below:

meteor install-sdk android
Have the mobile-config.js 
meteor add-platform android
meteor build ~/your-output-dir --server=yourapp.meteor.com
Then you will have your .apk file in ~/your-output-dir/android/unaligned.apk.

and I check the directory I do not have the android folder

But that generates me is a folder with winrar file, it does not generate file.apk

Here you can see what generates me

[image]

[image]

Hope someone could help me! Regards!

Comment: Can ypu post a screenshot of your files in the `output-dir/android/` folder?

Comment: the image this  above

Answer (score 0):

The TAR file archive with "bundle" folder in it is for your server deployment.

This means that your Meteor project does not have the `android` platform added, or that you requested a server only build.

Make sure your `.meteor/platforms` file contains a line with `android`. If not, execute the command `meteor add-platform android` as explained in the guide.